# Excel export issue

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, excel, c#-4.0

i am filling my excel sheet from asp.net , But in Excel i am getting error and incorrect values

Error:

CAREFUL, WE FOUND ONE OR MORE CIRCULAR REFERENCES IN YOUR WORKBOOK WHICH MIGHT CAUSE YOUR FORMULA TO CALCUALTE INCORRECTLY.

CODE:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Precise Technology Consultants";
            var DataContext = new EmployeeAtdDataContext();
            //var EmployeeAtd = DataContext.GetAttendance_Sp();
            IEnumerable<GetAtdRecord_SpResult> EmployeeAtd = DataContext.GetAtdRecord_Sp(null).ToList();
            var names = (from n in DataContext.EmployeeAtds select n).Distinct();
            ViewData["EmplID"] = new SelectList(names, "EmplID", "EmplName");
            return View(EmployeeAtd);

        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult ToExcel()
        {
            var DataContext = new EmployeeAtdDataContext();

            var grid = new GridView();
            grid.DataSource = DataContext.GetAtdRecord_Sp(null).ToList();
            grid.DataBind();

            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=AttendanceSheet.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

            Response.Charset = "";
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            grid.RenderControl(htw);

            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

SQL QUERY:

```
WITH Times AS
(   SELECT  emp.EmplID, 
            emp.EmplName,
            InTime = MIN(atd.RecTime),
            OutTime = MAX(atd.RecTime),
            TimeWorked = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(atd.RecTime), MAX(atd.RecTime)),
            OverTime = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(atd.RecTime), MAX(atd.RecTime)) - 480,
            [DateVisited] = atd.RecDate
    FROM    AtdRecord atd 
            INNER JOIN HrEmployee emp 
                ON atd.EmplID = emp.EmplID 
    GROUP BY emp.EmplID, emp.EmplName, atd.RecDate
    HAVING COUNT(atd.RecTime) > 1
)
SELECT  t.EmplID,
        t.EmplName,
        t.InTime,
        t.OutTime,
        t.DateVisited,

        TimeWorked = CONVERT(CHAR(5), DATEADD(MINUTE, t.TimeWorked, 0), 8),
        OverTime = CASE WHEN t.OverTime < 0 THEN '-' ELSE '' END +
                                CONVERT(CHAR(5), DATEADD(MINUTE, ABS(t.OverTime), 0), 8)
FROM    Times t
```

using MVC 3 and linq to sql

Check the last column, Overtime, ti should dispplay a value e.g. -07:27 but it doesn't
[image]

Comment: Troubleshoot the circular reference from within Excel. It has tools to do that. Use them.

Comment: i did but it temporarily removes that, i don't want customer or user to go through all this, there must eb a way to solve it

Comment: The idea is to identify the circular reference by inspecting it with Excel. Now you know which cell is the problem. Then go back to your code and fix the problem there.

Comment: whole column has issue , OVERTIME Column

Comment: i guess this query is causing proble, before this i used another query which worked correctly and data transported perfectly but since i used this query (it has character concatenation at end) it is causing problem

Comment: Mate, without having access to your SQL data source it's really impossible to tell what data is causing a problem. A  circular reference in Excel is ALWAYS caused by a formula. So go to Excel, find the cell with the circular reference. What is the formula?

Comment: It says, ERROR in Value: Value in formula is of wrong datatype, ERROR IN CELL g2, -7:29

Comment: Sooo? What is the formula in cell G2?

Comment: @teylyn $G$39    this one

Comment: Man, this is like pulling teeth. What does G39 refer to? You need to resolve the reference and follow each cell reference through to find the root of the circular reference.

Comment: ok ok i have figured out the issue, it's because of negative values which i am sending, it only should contain +constants but PROBLEM IS THAT I DO HAVE TO SEND NEGATIVE VALUES

Answer (score 2):

A circular reference in Excel is always caused by a formula. Find the cell that contains the circular reference with the tools that Excel offers. Then drill into the formula references in the problem cell and resolve all references until you find the cause of the circular reference.

Comment: mam, actually i don't know that how to find particular formulas on cell

Comment: If there is a formula in an Excel cell, it may refer to other cells. And these other cells may refer to other cells. And somewhere in the chain of references to cells there may be a circular reference. Just follow the references and use your brain to identify the circular reference.  If you don't know how Excel works, how can you write an application that creates Excel files?